# rigify stretching bones

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I've recently had a problem and I want to know how to fix it.
My probleme is when I move the bones in rigify I don't want them to stretch, because when they stretch the leg or arm gets messy and taller than it should be.

My second question is: How do I deal with elbows controllers so that the arm looks real when rigging?
My third question is: How do I add eyes and face controllers to the rig so that I can control expressions of face without messing with the body rigs

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time, you have three separate questions here.

Comment: well they're three questions for the same concept, Riggify

Comment: @AhmedMissoum It is still 3 separate questions: They are different enough to be easier to answer/more searchable as separate questions, please edit the post to remove the other two and ask them as separate questions

Answer (score 5):

The first two questions are related I will focus on them.
The stretching you face only appears with inverse kinematics (IK) when you move the control bone in a impossible position, this is used for cartonic exaggeration.

You can disable this by setting the Auto Stretch IK slider to 0.

[image]

The elbow has an IK-target which can be controlled as knees with a ball shaped control.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The stretching can also be caused by the armature being scaled in the object mode. Check that all scale variables are set to one.

https://blenderartists.org/t/problem-with-bones-in-armature-streching-when-rotated/542671